# How to upload .csv file from S-3 bucket to Redshift as new table under certain schema using Python3 in efficeint way?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-redshift, pandasql

I am trying to upload pandas dataframe to Redshift database using jupyter notebook. I went through the following links:

[How to write data to Redshift that is a result of a dataframe created in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402995/how-to-write-data-to-redshift-that-is-a-result-of-a-dataframe-created-in-python)

Python: 3.6

Windows: 10

Here is the code:

```
import psycopg2
import pandasql as ps
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


sql_conn=create_engine('postgresql://{}: 
   {}@{}:XXXX/{}'.format(user,password,host,db))


df.to_sql('data',con=sql_conn,schema="schema",
                index=False,if_exists='replace')
```

1. Tha table has millions of record and 100's of columns and it take hours to get uploaded.
2. How can I upload the using `s3` bucket using python and then upload to Redshift?

I tried this link:

[How to copy csv data file to Amazon RedShift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261743/how-to-copy-csv-data-file-to-amazon-redshift)

```
toRedshift = "COPY final_data from 's3://XXX/XX/data.csv' CREDENTIALS 
'aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXXX' removequotes  
 delimiter ',';"
 sql_conn.execute(toRedshift)
```

Error: Cannot COPY into nonexistent table final_data .

How to create table in Redshift using `S3` csv file in Python? Any efficinet way to do it without defining column types?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue today using COPY via psql. I've seen lots of inconsistency when running COPY commands in AWS console as well.